# Connecting two Combo-boxes with html and js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make these two combo-boxes join each other. But, my problem is, that my second combo-box cannot change if I select the category.

This is what I've done.

**HTML CODE**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<label for="JenisBarang">Jenis Barang</label>
<br>
<select id="JenisBarang" name="JenisBarang">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Mouse</option>
    <option value="1">Keyboard</option>
    <option value="2">Webcam</option>
</select>
<br>

<label for="PilihBarang">Pilih Barang</label>
<br>
<select id="PilihBarang_0" name="PilihBarang_0" style="display: inline;">
    <option value="1">Asus GX-1000</option>
    <option value="2">Logitech M238 Edisi : Burung Hantu</option>
    <option value="3">Logitech M238 Edisi : Astronot</option>
    <option value="4">Logitech M238 Edisi : Musang</option>
    <option value="5">Logitech M238 Edisi : Kera</option>
    <option value="6">Lenovo N700</option>
    <option value="7">Asus Gladius</option>
</select>
<select id="PilihBarang_1" name="PilihBarang_1" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">Logitech K400r</option>
    <option value="2">Logitech MK240</option>
    <option value="3">Asus GK2000</option>
</select>
<select id="PilihBarang_2" name="PilihBarang_2" style="display: none;">
    <option value="1">Lenovo Webcam</option>
    <option value="2">Logitech C920</option>
</select>
<br>
```

**Java Script CODE**

```
<script>
    function change_product(evt)
    {
    var JenisBarang=document.getElementById('JenisBarang'),whichstate;

    whichstate=JenisBarang.options[state.selectedIndex].value;

    for(var i=0;i<JenisBarang.options.length;i++)
       document.getElementById('PilihBarang_'+i).style.display=(i==whichstate ? 'inline':'none');
    }
</script>
```

**Dictionary**

- *JenisBarang* means the category ex Mouse
- *PilihBarang* means the items ex Mouse Logitech M185

Comment: do you want to show only the relevant products in  the 2nd combo boxes, after selecting the first combo box?? is that right?

Comment: @OmalPerera yes of course.. i think the code on javascript is something not worked.. if yes, please let me know.. thanks :D

Comment: Do you need to set onchange="change_product()" in the top select?

Comment: @machnaimh if it's work, it's fine to add it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the following Code. use `value` specify options in the second combo box. It is a simple code hope nothing to explain.. I have placed couple of comments.

```js
$("#comboBox1").change(function() {
  if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
    /* Get all the options in second Combo box*/
    $(this).data('options', $('#comboBox2 option').clone());
  }
  var id = $(this).val();
  var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
  $('#comboBox2').html(options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="comboBox1" id="comboBox1">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">Mouse</option>
  <option value="2">Keyboard</option>
  <option value="3">WebCam</option>
</select>

<!-- Second Combo Box-->
<select name="comboBox2" id="comboBox2">
  <option value="1">Mouse Model 1</option>
  <option value="1">Mouse Model 2</option>
  <option value="1">Mouse Model 3</option>
  <option value="2">Keyboard model 1</option>
  <option value="2">Keyboard model 2</option>
  <option value="2">Keyboard model 3</option>
  <option value="3">webcam model 1</option>
  <option value="3">webcam model 2</option>
</select>
```

**Edit** : JS Fiddle link [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5qccaLdu/)

Comment: after i try it, the JS still cannot change the second combo box.. i understand this logic.. but, it's still not working after i implement it..

Comment: Code is working fine. I double checked it.
I saved the code in JS Fiddle too for your convenience. please see the code from here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5qccaLdu/) it has places codes in different sections (html, JS)

Comment: i'll try it once again.. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: finally, on my project i didn't use this code because idk why it cannot worked in my html haha.. but thanks for mention it..